# Open somebody a whole new world

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Context: our software aims at helping graphic designers to better design.

So I think it is grammatically correct to say "Our software will open a whole new world for graphic designers".

But I would like to move "graphic designers" before "a whole new world" to stress the latter. So is it grammatically correct to say "Our software will **open for graphic designers** a whole new world." or "Our software will **open graphic designers** a whole new world."?

If none of the two sentences are correct, is there any other word that could replace "open" to connect "graphic designers" and "a whole new world"?

Comment: What does "grammarly correct" mean? That isn't even a thing. :)  Have you ever heard about anyone opening people things? I haven't.

Comment: then is "open for somebody a whole new world" correct grammarly?

Comment: "Grammarly" is a browser extension that checks your spelling and grammar. "Grammatically" is an adverb used in the English language, and probably what you meant to use in your question and comment.

Comment: @Esther indeed...

Comment: Maybe "Our software will broaden horizons for graphic designers" or "... broaden graphic designers' horizons"?

Comment: I've got "*For graphic designers,* our software will open a whole new world" or "Our software will *bring* graphic designers a whole new world."

Comment: "...give graphic designers a whole new world" or "...lead graphic designers to a whole new world". I'm sure there are questions here about similar constructions and issues of ordering, although it's sometimes hard to know what to search for.